# How to make overlay-menu return to default state when menu link is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I've been trying to make a overlay-menu i have tweaked, return to default state when I press one of the menu buttons/options. I don't know how to do this, but I suspect I need some JavaScript magic to make this work. (I dont know how to JavaScript tho, wich is a problem)

Menu can be found here:https://codepen.io/NilMag/pen/WxeXEP

Thanks for reading trough my post, and hopefully it's nothing major.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward solution using a bit of JavaScript.

```
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
var navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".scroll");

for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        toggle.checked = !toggle.checked;
    });
}
```

What's happening here is we've attached a click event listener to every single menu item. This is done by querying and looping through all menu elements via the "scroll" class. Once any of these elements is clicked, the toggle input's "checked" property is flipped.

The rest is handled by the CSS already available in your Pen :)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with this. I hope others can use this for their own projects if they run into a simular problem.  :)

Comment: No problem at all! If you're satisfied with my response, would you mind marking it as the answer? Others will see it and be more likely to put the code to use themselves :) Cheers.